# Django: What is the smartest way connect models for two types of clients (individual and company) to the address model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am working on developing a CRM like application using Django and I've stumbled upon a problem. The company which will use the app has private individuals as clients but also other companies. As they have different fields I created two separate models:

```
class PersonAccount(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    personal_id_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)
    document_series = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    document_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    document_emission_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    document_expiration_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    sex = models.ForeignKey(Sex, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    workplace = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nationality = models.ForeignKey(Geography, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    observations = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Person account: " + self.last_name + " " + self.first_name  

class CompanyAccount(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    chamber_of_commerce_reg_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)
    company_unique_id_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)
    company_type = models.ForeignKey(CompanyType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_nationality = models.ForeignKey(Geography, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_activity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_representative = models.ForeignKey(PersonAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    observations = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Commpany account: " + self.last_name + " " + self.first_name
```

I want to connect them both to an address model:

```
class AccountAddress(models.Model):
    address_type = models.ForeignKey(AddressType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    buliding = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    entrance = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    floor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    appartment_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Geography, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='account_country')
    province = models.ForeignKey(Geography, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='account_province')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return  "Account address: " + str(self.account) + " - " + str(self.address_type)
```

The thing is I am fairly new to Django and the only solution I currently see is to connect the actual Address model to PersonAccount and then create another one to connect to CompanyAccount. I am sure there must be another way but, although I've been searching and reading for a while, I can't seem to find nothing that fits my needs.

Could you please give me a hand? Thank you!

Comment: Does the child companies have other child companies?

Comment: I'm probably missing something - but I don't see why you can't have one `Address` model (as shown above) and have both of the models representing accounts have a `ForeignKey` relationship to it.

Comment: Why create Table for "sex" ? There is more than 2 (M/F) ?

Comment: @Ramy Mohammed No, I did not consider that as in this case it's not relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either define a parent `Account` class for `CompanyAccount` and `PersonAccount` (allowing you to save some code by moving common fields to the parent class) and define a `ForeignKey` on `AccountAddress`:

```
class AccountAddress(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Or you can define a many-to-many relationship on the individual account models instead of a foreign key in `Address`:

```
class CompanyAccount(models.Model):
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(AccountAddress)
```

The second solution allows sharing of addresses between accounts; in the first one only one account is associated with one address. You can have several addresses per account with both.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I eventually went with a many-to-many relationship after also exploring for a bit the concrete inheritance. I have one question though: I noticed that an extra table is created for the associations between accounts and addresses; wouldn't this lead to poor performance, if the database contains a large number of records, due to the need to join those extra tables? Thank you again.

Comment: M2M relationships with an intermediate table are the best solution for the use case they cover; you'd have to have quite a few clients (in the millions) before this becomes an issue. The question is if you need a M2M relationship, i.e. if you need to be able to associate the same address object to several clients. Good luck!

Comment: I wanted to associate one or more addresses to one account (be it person or company) without reusing them for other accounts but didn't know how. I also wanted to have only one table for the addresses.